# Какой смартфон для тестирования купить?

Tags: android-sdk, android

Я разрабатываю приложения для Android 4.0 и выше.  На данный момент у меня уже есть HTC One Android 4.4.3 KitKat. Какой смартфон можно купить для тестирования, чтобы на нем можно было быстро менять прошивку и на котором есть популярные прошивки (CM, MIUI) и т. д.

Comment: Должны же быть какие-то эмуляторы. Всяко быстрее чем телефон перепрошивать каждый раз. The Android SDK includes a mobile device emulator — a virtual mobile device that runs on your computer. The emulator lets you develop and test Android applications without using a physical device.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри сначала, может тебе досточно будет и твоего текущего смартфона. А так Galaxy и Nexus довольно распространенны.
http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=m7